# Google places nearbysearch not returning empty array when not possible

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

So, I have 2 photos which I have taken the exif gps data out of to then execute a search for what is nearby. The photos are taken 10 feet (3 meters) apart.
The only thing that strikes me as different at all is in the example that does not work, the latitude has more decimal places.

In the code example. Example 1 is successful, example 2 is not.

```js
const exampleOne = '10.09675,99.82821666666666'
const exampleTwo = '10.099127833333334,99.82723333333334'
const secret = '######'

const options = {
      uri: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json',
      qs: {
        location: exampleOne,
        radius: 50,
        key: secret

      },
      headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
      },
      json: true
    };

const parsedBody = await rp(options)
```

I am at a loss. I have been looking for known issues.

Comment: 1) Your code cannot be run/used as it is 2) You haven't even described what the problem is 3) You haven't shared any error / warning / log or whatever 4) I strongly suggest that you read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: exampleTwo is 50 meters off shore in the middle of the water... ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s90nxu2g/2/))

Comment: This issue has been discussed in this public bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/233252610